# Problem downloading youtube videos using Free Download Manager

Tags: youtube, download-manager

Free Download Manager (FDM) [claims](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/features.htm) to be able to download flash videos from various sites including Youtube.

I follow the directions given [here](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/youtube.htm) to download Youtube videos. The only thing FDM downloads is the html file with the name `watch`.

How can I make FDM to download Youtube videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube sometimes changes its protocols, which can make video-download tools stop working until they are updated. FDM might just be in such a state. If this is the case, you can either wait until it is updated, or try another free tool, such as [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/), which seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 4):

Use http://www.keepvid.com

Much easier than installing software on your computer and allows you to select which format you would like to download in.

I understand this does not help you with your program, but it is an easier solution than what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you cannot queue downloads using keepvid, that is why I have to use a download manager

Answer (score 3):

Add the video link from Youtube to Keepvid, and find a suitable format and file size of your choice. Right-click on the link of that particular file download link. There you will find an option to download using FDM. Click, and you have your Youtube video downloaded.

I too, tried just pasting the link to FDM directly but failed, and then found this solution.

Comment: keepvid requires java!

Answer (score 1):

You could try my one:
http://www.justpip.com/videodownloader/

It supports downloads from 3 popular video download sites and I regularly update it.
Basically YouTube often change the layout of the page and this breaks programs and websites which are looking for particular sections from which the download links can be made.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading video, you must open Mozilla browser and in a state connected directly to YouTube site, then open video you want to download. Open FDM and paste the URL link to Create flash video download dialog box

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution** that doesn't require installing additional software (malware):

Copy video URL from Youtube. Paste it in [www.en.savefrom.net](http://www.en.savefrom.net)
In the right side of the screen you will see the download links (one for each resolution available).
Click the link to download the movie OR use FDM to fast download the movie.

:)

Answer (score 0):

actually you only have to upgrade your FDM version. just download latest version then you go to flash video donwloads tab. then start to add download.. by pasting the Youtube link.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use a download manager - play the video online, then after it has finished go to your browser's cache folder. Find the file (usually about 20 to 40MB in size) and move it to your desired location. Open a Command Prompt and follow the steps below:

1. Type `ren sourcefilename newfilename.avi` where *sourcefilename* is the name of the file copied from the cache, and *newfilename* is the desired name for the video.
2. Close the Command Prompt.
3. Play the video easily.